# Getting XML Numbered Entities with PHP 5 DOM

Tags: php, utf-8, special-characters, domdocument, entities

I am new here and got a question that is tricking me all day long.

I've made a PHP script, that reads a website source code through cURL, then works with DOMDocument class in order to generate a sitemap file.

It is working like a charm in almost every aspect. The problem is with special characters.

For compatibility reasons, sitemap files needs to have all special chars encoded as numbered entities. And I am not achieving that.

For example, one of my entries - automatically read from site URLs, and wrote to sitemap file - is:

*[http://www.somesite.com/serviços/redesign/](http://www.somesite.com/servi%C3%A7os/redesign/)*

On the source code it should looks like:

*http://www.somesite.com/servi**ç**os/redesign/*

Just this. But unfortunately, I am really not figuring it out how to do it.

Source code file, server headers, etc... everything is encoded as UTF-8.

I'm using DOMDocument and related extensions to build the XML. (Basically, DOMDocument, $obj->createElement, $obj->appendChild).

htmlentities gives **ç** instead of **ç**
str_replace does not work. It makes the character just vanish in the output.

I was using $obj->createElement("loc", $url); on my code, and just now I read in PHP manual that I should use $document->createTextNode($page), in order to have entities encoding support.

Well, it is not working either.

Any idea on how to get unstuck of this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the filter extension:

$url = filter_var($url, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_HIGH)

Before use it. This makes a better result than any other solutions I've tried (bcoz it's RFC compliant).

Answer (score 1):

htmlentities has a 3rd argument = the charset to use ie

```
htmlentities($string,ENT_COMPAT,"UTF-8");
```